# How to fill the custom columns with joined values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like:

```
    SELECT `main_table`.*,
       IF(sosh.status = 'pending_payment', sosh.created_at, null)      AS `pending_payment_status_datetime`,
       IF(sosh.status = 'processing_payd', sosh.created_at, null)      AS `processing_payd_status_datetime`,
       IF(sosh.status = 'processing', sosh.created_at, null)           AS `processing_status_datetime`,
       IF(sosh.status = 'complete', sosh.created_at, null)             AS `complete_status_datetime`,
       IF(sosh.status = 'shipping_ready', sosh.created_at, null)       AS `shipping_ready_status_datetime`,
       IF(sosh.status = 'shipping_ready_cod', sosh.created_at, null)   AS `shipping_ready_cod_status_datetime`,
       IF(sosh.status = 'shipping_in_progress', sosh.created_at, null) AS `shipping_in_progress_status_datetime`,
       IF(sosh.status = 'closed', sosh.created_at, null)               AS `closed_status_datetime`,
       IF(sosh.status = 'archived', sosh.created_at, null)             AS `archived_status_datetime`,
       IF(sosh.status = 'withdraw', sosh.created_at, null)             AS `withdraw_status_datetime`,
       IF(sosh.status = 'canceled', sosh.created_at, null)             AS `canceled_status_datetime`
FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table`
         LEFT JOIN `sales_order_status_history` AS `sosh` ON sosh.parent_id = main_table.entity_id
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`;
```

I have 2 tables:

**sales_order_grid (where the main data is)**

**sales_order_status_history (where I want to attach the status data)**

I need to fetch custom columns values of the latest statuses (I mean there could be more than one status for the order, but the date differs).

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: What determines a status is later than the other?

Comment: @Nae there is a column in sales_order_status_history table: created_at

Comment: Does sales_order_status_history have unique id, what's the field name if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want an aggregation query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'pending_payment')  AS `pending_payment_status_datetime`,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'processing_payd') AS `processing_payd_status_datetime`,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'processing')           AS `processing_status_datetime`,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'complete')             AS `complete_status_datetime`,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'shipping_ready')       AS `shipping_ready_status_datetime`,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'shipping_ready_cod')   AS `shipping_ready_cod_status_datetime`,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'shipping_in_progress') AS `shipping_in_progress_status_datetime`,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'closed',)               AS `closed_status_datetime`,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'archived')             AS `archived_status_datetime`,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'withdraw' )             AS `withdraw_status_datetime`,
       SUM(sosh.status = 'canceled')             AS `canceled_status_datetime`
FROM `sales_order_grid``main_table` LEFT JOIN
     `sales_order_status_history` `sosh`
     ON sosh.parent_id = main_table.entity_id
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`;
```

This *may* fix the problems you are having.

EDIT:

You are asking for the *latest* statuses.  Then the logic is:

```
SELECT so.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sosh.status = 'pending_payment' THEN sosh.created_at END) AS pending_payment_status_datetime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sosh.status = 'processing_payd' THEN sosh.created_at END) AS processing_payd_status_datetime,
       . . . 
FROM sales_order_grid so LEFT JOIN
     sales_order_status_history `sosh`
     ON sosh.parent_id = so.entity_id
GROUP BY so.entity_id;
```

Comment: thank you! That solves my problem. Could you please explain me how MAX() knows to take latest created_at field?

Comment: @AlexYeremenko . . . `created_at` is a date/time value (presumably).  `MAX()` works on such values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a status is later than the other if its created_at is later then you could use:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*,
   IF(sosh.status = 'pending_payment', sosh.created_at, null)      AS `pending_payment_status_datetime`,
   IF(sosh.status = 'processing_payd', sosh.created_at, null)      AS `processing_payd_status_datetime`,
   IF(sosh.status = 'processing', sosh.created_at, null)           AS `processing_status_datetime`,
   IF(sosh.status = 'complete', sosh.created_at, null)             AS `complete_status_datetime`,
   IF(sosh.status = 'shipping_ready', sosh.created_at, null)       AS `shipping_ready_status_datetime`,
   IF(sosh.status = 'shipping_ready_cod', sosh.created_at, null)   AS `shipping_ready_cod_status_datetime`,
   IF(sosh.status = 'shipping_in_progress', sosh.created_at, null) AS `shipping_in_progress_status_datetime`,
   IF(sosh.status = 'closed', sosh.created_at, null)               AS `closed_status_datetime`,
   IF(sosh.status = 'archived', sosh.created_at, null)             AS `archived_status_datetime`,
   IF(sosh.status = 'withdraw', sosh.created_at, null)             AS `withdraw_status_datetime`,
   IF(sosh.status = 'canceled', sosh.created_at, null)             AS `canceled_status_datetime`
FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `sales_order_status_history` AS `sosh` ON sosh.parent_id = main_table.entity_id
LEFT JOIN `sales_order_status_history` AS `sosh2` ON sosh2.parent_id = main_table.entity_id
-- latest of sosh
  AND sosh2.created_at > sosh.created_at
WHERE sosh2.created_at IS NULL
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`;
```